# xsl namespace uri transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

Given an xml document where a versioning scheme has been implemented in the namespaces, what xslt can I apply to transform all the uris, mapping the document to the new version?

I don't know what namespaces a document will use, or how the references will be organised within the document.

e.g.

```
<a:add
    xmlns:a="urn:_2018_1.a" 
    xmlns:b="urn:_2018_1.b" 
    xmlns:c="urn:_2018_1.c"
    ....
>
...
```

to

```
<a:add
    xmlns:a="urn:_2019_1.a" 
    xmlns:b="urn:_2019_1.b" 
    xmlns:c="urn:_2019_1.c"
    ....
>
...
```

Comment: People who use namespaces like this should be shot at dawn, but I guess XSLT would become redundant if everyone designed their XML correctly...

Comment: @MichaelKay There will always be need to transform XML correctly designed for one purpose to another XML designed correctly for another purpose.

Comment: @Chomah Are you sure you need to do this? It should be enough to transform **nodes** from old namespaces/s to new, and leave it to the XSLT processor to provide the necessary namespace declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2 and 3 you can create namespace nodes using `xsl:namespace` so

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">

<xsl:param name="old-ns-year" select="'2018'"/>
<xsl:param name="new-ns-year" select="'2019'"/>

<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{replace(namespace-uri(), $old-ns-year, $new-ns-year)}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="namespace::*, @*, node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="namespace::*">
    <xsl:namespace name="{name()}" select="replace(., $old-ns-year, $new-ns-year)"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" namespace="{replace(namespace-uri(), $old-ns-year, $new-ns-year)}" select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

should give you an idea, at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifpe it transforms

```
<a:add
    xmlns:a="urn:_2018_1.a" 
    xmlns:b="urn:_2018_1.b" 
    xmlns:c="urn:_2018_1.c"
>
</a:add>
```

into

```
<a:add xmlns:a="urn:_2019_1.a" xmlns:b="urn:_2019_1.b" xmlns:c="urn:_2019_1.c">
</a:add>
```

using Saxon 9.8.

Comment: Thanks. Is XSLT 2 and 3 the only realistic option? I'm working in Java and would prefer to lean on what's built in than add additional dependencies.

Comment: XSLT 1 has no `xsl:namespace` element to construct new namespaces, that's the main function of XSLT 2 or 3 needed to make this work in a generic and compact way. I am no longer used to think in XSLT 1 terms, let's wait what the XSLT 1 aficionados will suggest you.

Comment: If you're working in Java then there's really very little excuse to be using a version of  XSLT that is now almost 20 years old.

Comment: In fact there is no pure XSLT 1.0 solution to this, but there is a solution using XSLT 1.0 plus the node-set() extension. To create a namespace dynamically in XSLT 1.0, first construct an element node in that namespace using `<xsl:element name="yy:dummy" namespace="{$uri}`/>, put this in a variable, convert the variable to a node-set using the node-set extension, then select and copy the namespace node using `<xsl:copy-of select="xx:node-set($dummy)//namespace::yy"/>`